# How may I inject input to a terminal with terminator?

Tags: shell, automation, wayland, xdotool, terminator

This is a specific question relating to use the `terminator` XTerm app for the general problem of inject or send shell command strings to a `terminator` panel.  I am looking for a replacement for existing scripts that use `xdotool` to send command strings to the current terminal Tab/Panel.  Under `Wayland` that would be a security violation (*understandably*).  Naturally, `xdotool` is `X-Org` thing (not `Wayland`).

I thought of `terminator` because `terminator` lets me group panels and send the same command to each panel/session in the group.  That tells me that `terminator` has the capacity and mechanism to send command strings to other panels.

I am questing for a method to use that ability to send input via `stdin` to a specific panel hosted by the same window.  Perhaps beyond that to any open `terminator` panel using the same `termiator` parent/host or using a known DBus channel.  I confess that it is a *presumption* that DBus could be used to succeeds in this objective.

I have not yet found a suggeston that this kind or ability is available.  My first step is to ask if one of you knows of a way this can be done in a 'clean' way.  It seems like the kind of 'need' or 'want' that a can be delivered with a plugin, if it doesn't exist yet.  There are several questions about sending input to bash or terminal sessions.  Not that I see as satisfactory.  Most involve low-level stuff with seemingly inconsistient performance or manipulating `screen` or `tmux` and a bit suboptimal.

It struck me that the grouping feature of `terminator` is at least a demonstration of of one shell script (session) sending to another shell session instance.  Although not necessarily how my `xdotool` scripts operate.  Here a couple of examples to flesh-out what this

**Use cases**

1. A launch script -- A terminal session used for a bit of workflow to (say) run `make` to build an app can launch the editor to open key files, open terminal to monitor the log  and input and output, etc.
2. Automate testing on CLI programs
3. Auto start terminal sessions (along with #1).
4. Automate -CLI based conversations

   - One notion here is for one script to send input to another terminal session,
   - Said sender can monitor output from redirect-ing `stdout`
5. Launch (GUI) apps via the console/teminal.

The common need here is to have 'something' running independently under a different terminal session/panel.

Best case here is that the facility exists and I just haven't found the "How to" yet or that there's already a plugin that I can use or adapt/extend.  I do not mind looking into writing a plugin if that's the only way.  I would probably need to find a collaborator or two; do mention if you think this is something you'd like to see.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to reinvent PTYs via the more fragile mechanism of scripting graphical terminals with keystores. I think you'd be better off just using PTYs from a cli app, and optionally running that app in a graphical terminal.

Comment: @thatotherguy ... I do not agree, what is needed is equivalence to `xdotool` under Wayland while respecting the quite valid security concerns.  A `PTY` has limitaitons on how the required behaviour could get done.  Nevertheless, the `terminator` terminal app    _must  already be_ a PTY to do what it does.

Comment: I have encontered an existing [bug in `terminator`, issue 739: terminator -x <command> does not work...](https://github.com/gnome-terminator/terminator/issues/739).  This fail prevents a tab that runs a script from remaining _open_.  I did some checking, such a scrpt runs and then the tab closes. One can perform an operation.  It can't currently be used to _set-up_ a terminal session, _`autoexec`_ like.  Back in the day Digital Research DOS happily initialised on only `8-bits`.  With 64-bits, it seems _not-so-much_.

Comment: You can fake input, one byte at a time, into a tty line, using `ioctl` parameter `TIOCSTI`. See `man ioctl_tty`, or websearch matches for the word `TIOCSTI` for more details and examples.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the easiest method is to use a `terminator` profile and/or layout.  This 'ask ununtu' question has some tips:

- [How to start terminator with a custom command per window](https://askubuntu.com/questions/349385/how-to-start-terminator-with-a-custom-command-per-window)

I also did some other testing and found the outcomes to be inconcsistient witht he documentation.  In the cited question they mention the `bash` rule; that is so.  If you want the tab to stay open it must end with a `bash` or shell instance.

Of special mention the `--execute <command>` option seemed like the *natural* approach to adopt.

It can work with the `terminator` command as long as the incantation is *worthy*. I don't think I'm being ironic either.  I have not yet managed to get `--execute`  toer work consistiently with the `remotinator` tool, however, alas.

I'm interested in better suggestions, so I won't "tick" this answer just yet.  Perhaps a future `terminator` release will tidy-up things and fulfill the promise in the documentation.